# Yii2 цикл Join'ов

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Здравствуйте, вопрос в заголовке, в Yii я делал цикл из такой строки:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
$criteria->join .= 'LEFT JOIN `products_attribute_value` '. $value .' ON (`'. $value .'`.`products_id`=`t`.`id`)';
}
```

все работало.

в Yii2 Критерий нет, как быть? в [доке](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md) не нашел решение

Comment: Хотелось бы больше узнать о задаче. А то не совсем ясно вчем проблема и как вы её решаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я нашел

[Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-query-builder.html)